# How to return the exact names of the new artifacts added to Jfrog artifactory using URL Trigger plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I need to poll the artifactory URL every night  and find out which file got added, and use that name of the new artifact as a parameter to trigger another job in Jenkins. But the URLTrigger plugin doesn't return the name of the new artifacts? Is there any way to derive that?

Answer (score 0):

I use groovy to run a curl command to extract and parse the metadata.xml to work out the jar name.

Assuming Artifactory has metadata content that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>path.to.application</groupId>
  <artifactId>jarName</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>6.1.12-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release>6.1.11</release>
    <versions>
      <version>6.1.11</version>
      <version>6.1.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20181122121509</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Thus the build information I want want is 'jarName-6.1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar'

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
//Assumed artifactory path to application.jar
def metaDataPath = 'https://your.artifactory.server/artifactory/path/to/application/jarName/maven-metadata.xml'

//Get the file using curl (you might need to use a proxy), with an api token for authentication
def metadataContent = 'curl -x<your-proxy:80> -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<your token>" -XGET ' + metaDataPath
metadataContent = metadataContent.execute().text

//Parse it to get the 'latest' element
def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parseText(metadataContent)
println parsedXml.versioning.latest.text() //6.1.12-SNAPSHOT
```

If your snapshot builds include a timestamp in their name, then you would need to use the returned `6.1.12-SNAPSHOT` to build a new metadata path:

`https://your.artifactory.server/artifactory/path/to/application/jarName/6.1.12-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`

To then repeat the extract and parse process to get the timestamped name from the child metadata.xml